# PayPal Credit + SetExpressCheckout

Tags: paypal, paypal-nvp

I am trying to setup PayPal Credit through the SetExpressCheckout API Operation. A standard payment is fine but I am having an issue setting the PayPal landing page to their Credit service.

I have seen this done elsewhere, for example on the Dyson and Apple webstores, where there is a separate PayPal Credit button which leads to a page where the customer can select their installment plan. As such: http://oi63.tinypic.com/r09w1c.jpg

Looking at the demos and documentation, it seems all that is needed are the options `LANDINGPAGE=Billing&USERSELECTEDFUNDINGSOURCE=BML`

This however doesn't work and takes the customer to an old style PayPal checkout.

Even the PayPal Credit demos on https://demo.paypal.com don't seem to work anymore when you change them from Static to Sandbox.

Has anyone managed to set this up successfully?

Comment: The screenshot you included is showing the signup for PayPal Credit, so I'm not sure what you're confused about..??  If you remove the parameters you mentioned from your SEC request you'll find that it doesn't default to the PayPal Credit form like you show in your screenshot.

Comment: Sorry, wrong screenshot, it is showing like this. http://oi66.tinypic.com/r1cvgz.jpg I have also added a screenshot of what I am trying to achieve.